# How can i stop watching my issue is assigned

Tags: jira

I have created some issues (type is bug). I am watching this issue. 
My issue can be assigned to different people and every time this happens I receive a notification email. 
How can i stop watching this particular event? I do not want to get emails which tells me who is assigned to my issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom notification scheme then assign it to the project and then under the `Issue Assigned (System)` item you can remove the `All Watchers` and `Reporter` from.

However this would be a **global** change for the project and means anyone else who is watching issues or is the reporter won't receive updates when an issue gets assigned to someone else.